# iOS autoreleasepool in main, and ARC alloc, release

Tags: objective-c

This is perhaps a naive question from iOS newbie.

I see that typical iOS application main.m has following code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));


    }
}
```

What is the point of having autoreleasepool around UIApplicationMain in iOS application? UIApplicationMain doesn't return till the application actually exits so why have UIApplicationMain() in autoreleasepool, which triggers 'free' for all the objects allocated during application's execution.

Comment: I found better phrase question & answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549711/autorelease-pools-in-objective-c-release-main-autoreleasepool?rq=1  However thanks to folks who responded to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, with LLVM compiler every thread has an autorelease pool by default and this is not needed. If you use a different compiler with a different implementation for autorelease pools (they are now a language feature), you are required to set up an autorelease pool for every thread. It doesn't matter that the call never returns, the pool has to be set up (and it can be drained thanks to it).

I can't find the duplicate question but I am sure it's there.

Answer (score 0):

From [Using Autorelease Pool Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html):

> Cocoa always expects code to be executed within an autorelease pool block, otherwise autoreleased objects do not get released and your application leaks memory. (If you send an `autorelease` message outside of an autorelease pool block, Cocoa logs a suitable error message.) The AppKit and UIKit frameworks process each event-loop iteration (such as a mouse down event or a tap) within an autorelease pool block.

TLDR: Running Cocoa code outside of an autorelease block is an error because it may leak memory.